# Problem with sDNA plugin setup in QGIS

Tags: qgis, sdna

When I open QGIS, a label appears:

`Please ensure sDNA version 3.0 or later is installed ensure the sDNA installation folder is set correctly inProcessing -> Options -> Providers -> Spatial Design Network Analysis`

The Plugin for spatial analysis is uploaded correctly. I have tried to download and install new versions but it is always the same story.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure you have installed the sDNA software in addition to the plugin (the actual sDNA software is a separate install).

From the [plugin page](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/sdna/)

> sDNA version 4.1 or above must be installed first from [cardiff.ac.uk/sdna](http://www.cardiff.ac.uk/sdna)

Then you *may* need to tell the sDNA plugin where  the sDNA software is installed (if you have installed the sDNA software somewhere other than the default):

```
"Processing -> Options -> Providers -> Spatial Design Network Analysis"
```

[image]